# Merge Statement in SQL not working for delete in Target

Tags: sql, merge, ssms, data-warehouse, dimensions

I want to use the merge statement to update the table PersonalDetails with the STG2PersonalDetails table.
I want it to update Target if Source is present matching on PersonalID.
I want it to insert into Target if Source is not present in target matching on PersonalID.
Last, I want to delete from Target if PersonalID is not present in the source table.
This is the code I have generated but its not working for the delete.
I think I may need to add a bit of extra script here but I am unsure.....
Wondered if anyone could help please.

```
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE [dbo].[PersonalDetails] AS T
USING dbo.[STG2PersonalDetails] AS S
ON (T.[PersonalID] = S.[PersonalID]) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT([PersonalID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Forename]
      ,[PreferredName]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Postnominal]
      ,[Degree]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[UserType]
      ,[LeaveDate]
      ,[Active]
      ,[ProfileStatus]
      ,[ProfileStatusID]) 
      VALUES([PersonalID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Forename]
      ,[PreferredName]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Postnominal]
      ,[Degree]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[UserType]
      ,[LeaveDate]
      ,[Active]
      ,[ProfileStatus]
      ,[ProfileStatusID])


WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET 
T.[PersonalID]      =S.[PersonalID],
T.[UserName]        =S.[UserName],
T.[Title]           =S.[Title],
T.[Forename]        =S.[Forename],
T.[PreferredName]   =S.[PreferredName],
T.[Surname]         =S.[Surname],
T.[Postnominal]     =S.[Postnominal],
T.[Degree]          =S.[Degree],
T.[Email]           =S.[Email],
T.[Phone]           =S.[Phone],
T.[UserID]          =S.[UserID],
T.[UserType]        =S.[UserType],
T.[LeaveDate]       =S.[LeaveDate],
T.[Active]          =S.[Active]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

Comment: I am not using Talend, I am using SSMS

Comment: So you pretty much want the PersonalDetails table to have exactly the same content as the STG2PersonalDetails table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add COMMIT instead of ROLLBACK

```
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE [dbo].[PersonalDetails] AS T
USING dbo.[STG2PersonalDetails] AS S
ON (T.[PersonalID] = S.[PersonalID]) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT([PersonalID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Forename]
      ,[PreferredName]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Postnominal]
      ,[Degree]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[UserType]
      ,[LeaveDate]
      ,[Active]
      ,[ProfileStatus]
      ,[ProfileStatusID]) 
      VALUES([PersonalID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Forename]
      ,[PreferredName]
      ,[Surname]
      ,[Postnominal]
      ,[Degree]
      ,[Email]
      ,[Phone]
      ,[UserID]
      ,[UserType]
      ,[LeaveDate]
      ,[Active]
      ,[ProfileStatus]
      ,[ProfileStatusID])


WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET 
T.[PersonalID]      =S.[PersonalID],
T.[UserName]        =S.[UserName],
T.[Title]           =S.[Title],
T.[Forename]        =S.[Forename],
T.[PreferredName]   =S.[PreferredName],
T.[Surname]         =S.[Surname],
T.[Postnominal]     =S.[Postnominal],
T.[Degree]          =S.[Degree],
T.[Email]           =S.[Email],
T.[Phone]           =S.[Phone],
T.[UserID]          =S.[UserID],
T.[UserType]        =S.[UserType],
T.[LeaveDate]       =S.[LeaveDate],
T.[Active]          =S.[Active]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
COMMIT TRAN;
GO
```